# Dozer deep mapping Set with in a Map

Tags: java, deep-copy, dozer

I have two classes `Test1.java` and `Test2.java` with a field `fieldName` of type `Map<String, Set<String>>`. When I try to map **Test1** to **Test2** using dozer, it throws the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.util.List
at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapCollection(MappingProcessor.java:561)
at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapOrRecurseObject(MappingProcessor.java:434)
at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapMap(MappingProcessor.java:586)
at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapOrRecurseObject(MappingProcessor.java:395)
at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapFromFieldMap(MappingProcessor.java:342)
at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapField(MappingProcessor.java:288)
at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:248)
at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:197)
at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:187)
at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:133)
at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:128)
at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.map(DozerBeanMapper.java:127)
at com.paypal.offers.common.util.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:25)
```

Why is it not able to identify the correct destination type of util.Set ? Do I have to add some hints ?